# i am getting error request failed 404 from a api when i do widget and unit testing in flutter

Tags: flutter, unit-testing, flutter-dependencies

**this is the test file**

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';
import 'package:flutter_train/components/api_handling/ApiHandlePost.dart';
import 'package:mocktail/mocktail.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class MockHttpClient extends Mock implements http.Client {}

void main() {
  testWidgets('Add product via HTTP POST', (WidgetTester tester) async {
    final mockClient = MockHttpClient();
    // Mock the HTTP POST request
    when(() => mockClient.post(
          Uri.parse(addProductUrl),
          headers:  {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
          body: jsonEncode({
            "title":"test",
            "description":"tested test"}),
        )).thenAnswer((_) async {
      // Simulate a successful response with the provided data
      final responseMap = {
        "title": "test",
        "description":"tested test"
      };
      final responseBody = jsonEncode(responseMap);
      return http.Response(responseBody, 200);
    });

    await tester.pumpWidget(MaterialApp(
      home: ApiHandlePost(httpClient: mockClient),
    ));

    // Enter text in the TextField with the label 'Title'
    await tester.enterText(find.widgetWithText(TextField, 'Title'), 'test');

    // Enter text in the TextField with the label 'Description'
    await tester.enterText(
        find.widgetWithText(TextField, 'Description'), 'tested test');

    // Tap the "Add Product" button
    await tester.tap(find.text('Add Product'));
    await tester.pumpAndSettle();

    // Verify that the product is displayed in the list
    expect(find.text('test'), findsOneWidget);
    expect(find.text('tested test'), findsOneWidget);
  });
}
```

**and this is the api handle for post**

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

// Define the API endpoint URLs
final String apiUrl = 'https://dummyjson.com/products';
final String addProductUrl = 'https://dummyjson.com/products/add';

class ApiHandlePost extends StatefulWidget {

final http.Client? httpClient;

  ApiHandlePost({required this.httpClient});


  @override
  _MyHttpPostAppState createState() => _MyHttpPostAppState();
}

class _MyHttpPostAppState extends State<ApiHandlePost> {
  TextEditingController titleController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController descriptionController = TextEditingController();

  List<dynamic> products = [];

  Future<void> addProduct() async {
    try {
      final response = await http.post(
        Uri.parse(addProductUrl),
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
        body: jsonEncode({
          'title': titleController.text,
          'description': descriptionController.text,
          /* Add other product data here */
        }),
      );

      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        final jsonData = json.decode(response.body);
        // Assuming the response contains a product object
        final newProduct = jsonData as Map<String, dynamic>;

        // Add the newly created product to the list
        setState(() {
          products.add(newProduct);
        });
        titleController.clear();
        descriptionController.clear();
      } else {
        print('Request failed with status: ${response.statusCode}');
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print('Error: $e');
    }
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    titleController.dispose();
    descriptionController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('HTTP POST Example'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
            StatefulBuilder(builder: (BuildContext context, StateSetter setState){
              return Card(
                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(
                        12.0), // Adjust the radius as needed
                  ),
                  child: Container( 
                    width: 300,
                    child:TextField(
                      enabled: true,
                    controller: titleController,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      labelText: 'Title',
                    ),
                  )));
            }), 
              StatefulBuilder(builder: (BuildContext context, StateSetter setState){
              return Card(
                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(
                        12.0), // Adjust the radius as needed
                  ),
                  child: Container( 
                    width: 300,
                    child:TextField(
                      enabled: true,
                    controller: descriptionController,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      labelText: 'Description',
                    ),
                  )));
            }), 
              ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  addProduct();
                },
                child: Text('Add Product'),
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 16),
              Expanded(
                child: ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: products.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    final product = products[index];
                    return ListTile(
                      title: Text(product['title']),
                      subtitle:
                          Text(product['description'] ?? 'no description'),
                    );
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      );
  }
}
```

***I am getting error request failed 400.In UI part i take user input and pass it to the API. I am new to testing so a help would be valuable***

**i was expecting a successful test case as i tried this on postman**

```
{
            "title": "test",
            "description": "tested test"
}
```

**and got this as output**

```
{
    "id": 101,
    "title": "test",
    "description": "tested test"
}
```

I hope this is enough for the question you can ask me for more details.